# Evaluation method of content-based recommendation system with no known ground truth

Tags: precision

I am building a content-based recommendation system using cosine-similarity between 2 sets of texts A and B. For each document in A, I'll recommend top-n similar documents in B.

Because this is the first time that a recommendation is built on this dataset, there is no known ground truth (i.e, we have no prior data where users indicate a pair of documents are relevant/similar).

I plan to evaluate as follow:

1. Prepare a sample of N items from A and their top-10 recommendations from B.
2. Send this to a set of users.
3. Ask users to rate the similarity/relevance (either True or False).
4. For all items in N, calculate the average precision @1, @3, @5, @10.

May I know if this method is sound?

Secondly, I am also thinking of asking users to give a relevance score from 1 to 5 (1: least similar/relevant, 3: neutral, 5: most similar/relevant) => is there an evaluation metric that includes both precision@k and the rating score (instead of just true/false)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method can give you an estimate of the precision or positive predictive value of your recommendation system - it will tell you how many relevant items there are among the items you selected. It will not, however, tell you anything about the items you did not select, which could be quantified with measures like specificity or true negative rate.

I'd recommend that you do at least some assessment of items that you did *not* recommend. After all, a system that returns 8 relevant items in the top 10 might seem like good performance, until you find out that 9 out of 10 items you didn't recommend are also relevant! This is a somewhat extreme example, but it's generally good to know the overall prevalence of your target group, as well as to understand what a negative prediction tells you. By manually labeling only predicted positive samples, you lose the ability to discern anything about predicted negative samples.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used text similarity, so I think the ones that I did NOT recommend would have lower similarity scores. My dataset are similar to news. What kind of assessment of negative items can I do? Also, can I use the rating scale 1-5 as mentioned?

Comment: @hydradon You could just randomly sample non-recommended items, or sample based on some kind of similarity score bin. Ideally, I think you'd like to see that the "proportion of relevant items" goes down as the similarity score goes down, and you could look at that by sampling from items with score from 0 to 1, from 1 to 2, etc. Seeing a good chunk of relevant items outside the top 10 isn't necessarily a bad thing, so long as those items also have a high similarity score. If you go with a rating scale, you could do a direct correlation between similarity score and user rating.